# Cant use global variable as text for MDLabel in kivyMD (Beginner)

Tags: kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I need a help in KivyMD,

I am trying to change the text of MDLabel of screen WELCOME,
But Its showing blank.
I tried various ways from stack overflow to tackle this issue but it isnt even working,
Hopefully your answers will help others too,

**.py**

```
class WELCOME(Screen):
    b=StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(WELCOME, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    '''def on_enter(self, *args):
        global User
        self.add_widget(MDLabel(font_name='MyriadPro-Light.otf',
                                font_size=100,
                                pos_hint={'center_x':0.95, 'center_y':0.70},
                                text=User))'''
    def on_ented(self, *args):
        global User
        self.b=User
        return(self.b)
```

**.kv**

```
<WELCOME>:
    name: 'Welcome'
    on_enter:
        app.animate_card(welcard)
    MDLabel:
        text:root.on_ented()
        font_name: 'MyriadPro-Light.otf'
        font_size: 50
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.50,'center_y':0.75}
    MDLabel:
        id:welcard
        text:'Welcome ! \\n    '# root.manager.MY_GLOBAL
        font_name: 'MyriadPro-Light.otf'
        font_size: 50
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.50,'center_y':0.75}
```

And finally its coming out like this,
[image: Output is coming like this]

my take:
The function on_ented is initialized immediately before the run,
there should a way to stop that function.

Comment: Try changing `text:root.on_ented()` to `text:root.b`

Comment: Thanks For the change, But Its still not working..
I tried my level best using solutions on StackOverflow, I think this a very problematic issue.

Comment: Just noticed. The `on_ented` method should be `on_enter`.

Comment: Your reply means a lot to me, Will try that too..